# Change ion-view view-title in every pages

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, title

I change the view-title with $scope.name = user.name and then I use `<ion-view view-title="{{name}}">`

In the same page the change is done, but in other pages you can see the previous name, not updating.

I try with `<ion-view view-title>`, `<ion-view title>`, with nav-bar... and nothing.

Help, please!

Comment: Ok so each page have different routes and may be different controller . and in each controller you are specifying this $scope.title . and those changes are not getting reflected to your page . ?

Comment: I put $scope.name in one controller, but I thought with that was enough to change every titles, because i call to {{name}}.

When I pulse f5 the change can see it, I am freaking out

Comment: put in one controller only ? You have one controller only ?  if other views where you need to show this title , if they have different controller then they should contain this $scope.title .

Comment: Yes, I have a function for that, and I have some pages without controller because only serve to show data. For that only put it in one place. If in the others pages changes when I reload the page, why not do it with reload?

Comment: can you show your code here ? some snippet . may be it can help . case when you see and when you don't see. Code for both .

Comment: Well, in user.html I have:

`<ion-view view-title="{{name}}">`
[a list of names...]
 `<button ng-click="useThisName(item)">Click</button>`

In the controller I have:

$scope.useThisName = function (user) {        
        $scope.name = user.name
    }

So in user.html `<ion-view view-title="{{name}}">` changes in the moment but in the others no if i don't reload the app.

Comment: So it works fine for user.html and does not work for other . Do they have other controller / state ?

Comment: I want to see in a page without controller, i have to create it for this?

Comment: Yes you have to but How that page get called . just routing , no controller specified ? you can specify controller inline in html or in your route so they can have data and MVVM , view model binding can take place.

Comment: Welcome buddy . So i am adding it as an answer . You can accept it . (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so according to your conversation you were not referring any controller to other view file where title was not shown . So to make data binding we need controller file referring to a view file either inline or through a route

**So make controller for your view file and add $scope.title in each controller accordingly**

Answer (score 0):

According to me, your other pages must be under the scope of different controller.
For a quick-fix you can try:

```
$rootScope.name = user.name
```

Comment: Yes, if I try this i need pulse f5 to see the change in other pages :(

Comment: Then try putting this in a $timeout so that changes will be auto binded.

Comment: My friend, I do that but only change the local $scope, not the $rootScope.

Comment: If you are using $rootScope the how will it change local $scope?

Comment: Sorry, I try with booth, $scope.name = user.name and $rootScope.name =user.name. Only change the local.

I have doing in a function, i don't know if i have to use $rootScope.useThisName = function like i use $scope.useThisName?